# How to get rid of "%" symbol at the end of line when I am using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have been using the powerlevel9k theme on iterm and whenever I compile my C language code and executing the same I am getting a "%" symbol at the end.
How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Zsh shows the inverted `%` to let you know that your program forgot to print `\n` at the end of its output. For example, you would see it when you compile and execute the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { printf("hello world"); }
```

There are two things you can do. The first is to fix your C program. In the example above you could either use `puts` instead of `printf` or add `\n` at the end of the string.

In addition, you can customize the character that gets displayed by Zsh in circumstances like this. For example, you can use a red block by placing the following definition in `~/.zshrc`:

```
PROMPT_EOL_MARK='%K{red} %k'
```

P.S.

You might want to upgrade to powerlevel10k.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it currently -> `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''`

> Add this in .zshrc.

Referred from the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60364704/6072570) by Roman Perepelitsa.